Daily Transfer File
I have written a .bat file that creates a folder with the following code
echo off
mkdir "Peak (%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-2,2%)"

It runs and creates a directory called Peak with today's date.
I have also written a file that transfers only the files of interest to the specified folder.
Here is the .bat file
echo off
Move "C:\Peak495Win10\*.CHR" "C:\Users\james.presley\Desktop\Peak\Peak (08-15-24)"
Move "C:\Peak495Win10\*.RES" "C:\Users\james.presley\Desktop\Peak\Peak (08-15-24)"

What I want to do is combine them into one file that creates today's Peak (MM-dd-yy) directory and then transfers all the files of interest to that directory without to specify the moved files ending destination daily.
I want the program to assign the folder just created as the destination of the move.
How do I go about this?

So, use SET to create a variable with the newly created directory name.  Or, do a "chdir" to move into that directory, and "chdir .." afterward.

That can be done with the following lines: 1. @echo off 2. set "DestFolderName=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Peak\Peak (%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-2,2%)" 3. mkdir "DestFolderName" 4. move "C:\Peak495Win10\*.CHR" "%DestFolderName%\" 5. move "C:\Peak495Win10\*.RES" "%DestFolderName%\" That's it.

Some recommendations: 1. Read the answers on Time is set incorrectly after midnight. It is general better to use code for getting the current date in the wanted format from a region/country independent date string. 2. The international date format yyyy-MM-dd is much better than MM-dd-yy because of showing the list of directories in Windows File Explorer sorted alphabetically by name lists the directories with international date format at the same time also in correct chronological order.

That makes seeing the oldest and newest folder much easier. The batch file might delete in future the oldest X folders which is horrible to code with date format MM-dd-yy while a single command line can do it with date format yyyy-MM-dd. 3. The folder Desktop should contain only shortcut files (.lnk files) and not files of other types or a folder like Peak. It would be better removing Desktop\ from the second line and do following. Right click on the folder C:\Users\james.presley\Peak, click on Windows 11 on Show more options, and click in context submenu Send to on

the menu item Desktop (create shortcut). There is now a shortcut on your desktop with name Peak - Shortcut. Make your desktop visible, select this shortcut, press key F2 and rename the shortcut to just Peak. (The file extension .lnk is not shown by Windows default.) It is indeed so easy to create a shortcut of a folder or a file on your desktop. There is really no reason for having files or folders in the Desktop folder.

Or using the info from the previously mentioned link, you could do it in just two lines if you want that same date format. 1. @For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe \: . /NJH /L ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe " 123"') Do @Set "Today=%%H-%%I-%%G", 2. @%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "C:\Peak495Win10" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Peak\Peak (%Today:~,-4%%Today:~-2%)" *.chr *.res /Mov 1>NUL 2>&1.

If you were happy to change the date format, then a single line batch file could be used instead: @For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe \: . /NJH /L ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe " 123"') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "C:\Peak495Win10" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Peak\Peak (%%G-%%H-%%I)" *.chr *.res /Mov 1>NUL 2>&1.
